# How to get a bootstrap card to flip and stay flipped using css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, vuejs2

I am using Vue, css and JavaScript. I am able to get a specific card to flip when a I hold down the button, but the desired behavior would be that when pressing the button (not holding) the card would flip and reveal the back of the card, then from the back pressing the button you can flip the card again to the front. I've tried implementing this feature with Vue and css only but I could not accomplish it, so I decided to use vanilla Javascript and use `onclick` event. I have gut feeling that it's my css that's causing this issue but I've experimented quite a bit and can't figure it out. Help or recommendations would be appreciated, only looking to use Vue, vanilla JavaScript, and css. I am sorta new to Vue and css animations/transitions.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#CardsApp",
    data: {
        cards: [],
        isFetchingData: false
       
        
    },
    created: function() {
        this.isFetchingData = true;
        let vm = this;

        axios.get("http://localhost:52007/api/cards")
            .then(response => {
                vm.cards = response.data.slice()
                vm.isFetchingData = false;
            })
    }
    
})
```

```css
.card-title {
    font-family: getSchwifty, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: greenyellow;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-text {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#loadingImg {
  
    margin-bottom: 30vmin;
}

.card-flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.card-flip:active .flip, .card-flip.active .flip {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-flip,
.front,
.back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 38rem;
}

.flip {
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="CardsApp" v-cloak>


    <div class="container">
        <img id="loadingImg" v-if="isFetchingData" src="../../images/loading.gif" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="Loading" />

    </div>


    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="card in cards" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <!-- Card Flip -->
                    <div class="card-flip">
                        <div class="flip">
                            <div class="front">
                                <!-- front content -->
                                <div class="card border-success text-white  bg-dark mb-5" style="max-width: 20rem;">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/SquanchyCardLogo.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">

                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Cards For Squanchies</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text text-center" style="min-height: 7rem">{{card.frontText}}</p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <small class="text-muted">Card No. {{card.id}}</small>
                                        <button onclick="isFlipped()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm float-right">Flip this biaatch back!</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="back">
                                <!-- back content -->
                                <div class="card border-success text-white  bg-dark mb-5" style="max-width: 20rem;">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/SquanchyCardLogo.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">

                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Cards For Squanchies</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text text-center" style="min-height: 7rem">{{card.backText}}</p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <small class="text-muted">Card No. {{card.id}}</small>
                                        <button onclick="isFlipped()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm float-right">Flip this biaatch back!</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Card Flip -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- CardsApp ends-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Vue/vue-cards.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function isFlipped() {
        document.querySelector(".card-flip").classList.toggle("flip");
        console.log('Inside isFLipped function')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You sure you want to use the :active pseudo selector? Maybe try :visited or not put that in there?

Comment: @git-e-up I tried what you mentioned but still did not get the behavior I was expecting.